# Regular Expression to disambiguate between arbitrary parenthesis and an optional trailing parenthesis construct containing comma delimited arguments

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having a spot of trouble with a regular expression I've written, I would love to tinker with all the language elements of the regular expression syntax but sadly I'm running out of time on this particular work item so am having to defer to the greater regular expression gurus out there :)

### Platform

This is running using the .NET regex engine. I've used Expresso to create the pattern this far.

### The pattern so far

```
^
(?<BaseTable>
    (?# The quantifier here is simply too greedy, I thought just a lazy 
        modifier '?' would be appropriate?)
    (?# But instead I had to coax it along with a positive look ahead 
        assertion??? The lazy '*?' on it's own confused Expresso?)
    .*?(?=\([^(]+\)$|$)                     
)
(?# Handle a leading comma if there are comma delimited arguments)
(\(\s*(\s*,?\s*                             
    (?# All these arguments are optional but at least one of them has to 
        exist to qualify the trailing parenthesis as the arguments)
    (C\s*=\s*(?<CalenderYear>\d{4})
    |B\s*=\s*(?<YearOfBirth>\d{4})
    |S\s*=\s*(?<Scale>[\d.]+)\s*%?\s*
    |P\s*=\s*(?<Projection>[^,]+)
    |U\s*=\s*(?<Underpin>[\d.]+)\s*%?\s*))*
(?# This zero or one quantifier needs to be greedier than the BaseTable 
    quantifier)
\))?
```

### The test cases

```
PA(90)M(S=125.00 %,B=2011)
PA(90)M(S=125.00 %)
PA(90)M
PA(90)M(S=125.00 %,B=2011)
table(arbitrarytableparenthesis)(p=arguments,s=125.00%)
BaseTable(TableDetail)(B=2011,P=ProjectionArguments,S=115.00%,U=5.00%)
BaseTable(TableDetail)( B = 2011 , P = ProjectionArguments , S = 115.00 %, U = 5.00 %)
Base Table(with spaces)( B = 2011 , P = ProjectionArguments , S = 115.00 %, U = 5.00 %)
Only(ASuccessfulMatch)(S=125.00 %,P = CMI_2009_F [1.25%] + 1.25%)
Only(APartialMatch)
```

### The problem

All of the above produces good matches, apart from the last one. I need the entire last case `Only(APartialMatch)` to all be included in the named capture group `BaseTable`.

The `Only(APartialMatch)` needs to be disambiguated against the previous match `Only(ASuccessfulMatch)`.

Any help greatly appreciated! Cheers!

### Update

jsobo kindly provided an amended regular expression pattern, of which pushed the solution forward. It only accounts for one pair of arbitrary parenthesis before the trailing set of parenthesis- ultimately a flaw in how I framed the enquiry (many apologies). I'm hoping there is an amendment to the pattern that distinctly disambiguates between the trailing pair of parenthesis containing arguments and any other parenthesis that may exist in the `BaseTable` subcapture.

A few updated test-cases would therefore be:

```
Base Table(with spaces)Table Stuff(More Table Stuff)( B = 2011 , P = ProjectionArguments , S = 115.00 %, U = 5.00 %)
Base Table(with spaces)Table Stuff(More Table Stuff)Other table stuff(still more table stuff)( B = 2011 , P = ProjectionArguments , S = 115.00 %, U = 5.00 %)
Base Table(with spaces)Table Stuff(More Table Stuff)Other table stuff(still more table stuff)final base table stuff( B = 2011 , P = ProjectionArguments , S = 115.00 %, U = 5.00 %)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of your look ahead in the first group and just changed it to look for your pattern of

anything... ( anything ) optional more stuff before the next paren...

```
^(?<BaseTable>.*?\(.*?\)[^(]*)(\(\s*(\s*,?\s*(C\s*=\s*(?<CalenderYear>\d{4})|B\s*=\s*(?<YearOfBirth>\d{4})|S\s*=\s*(?<Scale>[\d.]+)\s*%?\s*|P\s*=\s*(?<Projection>[^,]+)|U\s*=\s*(?<Underpin>[\d.]+)\s*%?\s*))*\))?
```

so

```
^(?<BaseTable>.*?(?=\([^(]+\)$|$)))
```

became

```
^(?<BaseTable>.*?\(.*?\)[^(]*)
```

Comment: I didn't look at the rest of the regex (in detail) but it looks like it does what you want. NOTE: there was not a test case for calender year...

Comment: You are correct ... there wasn't a test case, but in the context of the alternation construct I'm not too fussed! I ran your expression, it matched. Well played!!! I'll decipher your modification to appreciate your adjustment, many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your submission, it was close, I've updated the question, there were a few test cases missing as you noted. The issue with the alternation construct I wasn't too worried about, there is an issue with the number of arbitrary pairs of parenthesis before the final pair though.

Comment: is the "BASETABLE" capture group suppose to get everything up until the last set of Parens?

Comment: yes, only if the last set of parenthesis contain an argument list as outlined in the alternation construct detailing the key value pairs where the key is equal to either C, B, S, P, or U. Otherwise the final set of parenthesis should also be considered part of the `BaseTable` subcapture. I couldn't quite bend my mind around it ... thanks for your help.